# Spring + Hibernate - transactions - concurrent database operations

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I need to read data from database, perform some logic and next write data to database in one atomic operation.

I need to make sure that this operations are fully thread safe, because there can be many threads  using this code.

What I am doing now is something like this:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class AccountBalanceChangeHandlerImpl implements AccountBalanceChangeHandler {

    private final Object mutex = new Object();

    @Inject
    private UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    @Override
    public Money handle(Long userAccountId, Money money) throws Exception {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            UserAccount userAccount = userAccountRepository.findOne(userAccountId);
            if (userAccount.getMoney().getCurrencyUnit().equals(money.getCurrencyUnit())) {
                userAccount.setMoney(userAccount.getMoney().plus(money));
            } else {
                BigDecimal currencyRate = getCurrencyConvertRate(money.getCurrencyUnit().getCurrencyCode(),
                        userAccount.getMoney().getCurrencyUnit().getCurrencyCode());
                userAccount.setMoney(userAccount.getMoney().plus(money
                        .convertedTo(userAccount.getMoney().getCurrencyUnit(), currencyRate, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
            }
            userAccountRepository.save(userAccount);
            return userAccount.getMoney();
        }
    }

    private BigDecimal getCurrencyConvertRate(String from, String to) throws Exception {
        //something here
    }

}
```

This code seems thread safe - I tested it on from 10 to 10000 threads and can't get it not working - after removing synchronized block it fails.

I just wanted to know is there a way to handle it on database level or do it better ?

I've read a lot about transactions, locks and tried @Transactional and @Lock in many ways, but I can not get it working.

Comment: There is totally no need to worry about thread safety, if you **always** designate beans with an appropriate / **right** scope.

Comment: Ok, so I created 500 beans ( there is a method for creating new object like this for each account change to handle it ) , each needs to modify one column in database, how can I not worry about thread safety ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: That is another separate question which has nothing to do with the current question. It goes to locking (JPA or whatever).

Comment: Man, you are not helping.

Comment: @Tiny You are wrong, he is asking about getting a database operation atomic, not about java thread-safety. Maybe he didn't used the perfect-exact words but if you read carefully it is clear what he is asking.

Comment: @aalku : Use of a `synchronized` block clearly implies thread-safety which in turn is very much discouraged in web app environment.

Comment: You should get `@Transacional` working. Current versions' doc is here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: @Tiny as you can read he try to remove `synchronized` but can't because `@Transactional` is not working for him.

Comment: @aalku : It is merely a guess but the question should then have constructed that way asking or stating why `@Transactional` does not work in a given situation.